# Define Spring dependency matching a Spring Boot version

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I am developing two projects.

Project 1 is a spring-boot application based on gradle for dependency management. This application defines extension-points. If - at runtime - an extension is found on the classpath, this extension is being called from the main application under certain circumstances.

Project 2 is such an extension. This extension should only provide low-level functionality. So basically, I need spring annotations and an `EntityManager` within the application but I would like to prevent the full spring-boot dependencies to be present on the compile-path.

The obvious (and not satisfactory) solution is to define a compileonly-dependency on a specific version of, say, `spring-context`. This is somewhat dangerous, as the spring-boot version may progress and it may be easy to forget to adjust the spring version.

Providing a compileOnly dependency to spring-boot-starter (or even the main project) is out of the question.

So, is there a clever trick to tell gralde to use "the spring-version coming with spring-boot-xxx"?

Comment: I'm not familiar with gradle but doesn't it have a concept like BOM (bill of materials) that you can import so that project2 can use only a specific version of a specific dependency defined/managed by spring-boot bom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you are within a forrest and not seeing the trees...

Thanks to the comment of @emrekgn I looked for BOM/Gradle/Spring and found... the spring boot dependency-management plugin.

Adding this to your gradle file will allow you to include dependencies matching to the spring boot version you are using:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.2'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
```

Obviously, you have to match the boot-version to your needs.